# What is the Max and Min values for Drools Salience

Tags: java, drools

As the title states, what the range of allowed values for Salience in Drools rule definitions?

I would think it would Int Max or And Int min, but I found no mention of it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

[In the source code](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-model/drools-canonical-model/src/main/java/org/drools/model/Rule.java#L15), the salience of a rule is keep as an Integer. So I assume that the max and min values are `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Hope it helps,